# PHP Check for NULL

Tags: php, mysql, null

Here is the below Code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablex");

if ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    if ($result['column'] == NULL) { print "<input type='checkbox' />"; }
    else { print "<input type='checkbox' checked />"; }
}
```

If the values are `NOT NULL` i still get the uncheked box. Am i doing something wrong from above, shoudnt `$result['column'] == NULL` work?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Im simply printing the checkbox. And its checked if the value is not null. It dosent seem to do that.. Hense it always goes into the first if statment

Comment: the code posted is missing a right paren and a right brace and i get down-voted for spotting that? *eyeroll*

Comment: Sry this might sound mean.. But i didnt ask for syntax problems.. I asked for the Null value.. And if there was syntax error.. the code will output the error. However said that i did see the bracket.. I didnt actually copy and paste my code.. it was more of a type it my self. PS it wasnt me who downvoted you :D

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use [is_null](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) or `===` operator.

```
is_null($result['column'])

$result['column'] === NULL
```

Comment: `$result['column'] === NULL` did not work. Worked `is_null($result['column'])`. Php version 7.0.

Answer (score 5):

How about using

`if (empty($result['column']))`

Comment: Using PHP's `empty()` function leaves too much room for interpretation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and is more of a language specific solution to a general programming scenario. If he uses `===`, he will have a solution that he can use in many languages.

Comment: empty also returns true if column is 0

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the value of the column is really NULL and not an empty string or 0.

Comment: i had results in two places... Its late and my brain is blown up.. Exactly what i did to figure it out :D

Comment: That's why fernyb's answer is not a preferable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
```

rather than

```
mysql_fetch_row($query)
```

The latter returns an normal array index by integers, whereas the former returns an associative array, index by the field names.

Comment: sry im using mysql_fetch_array()... put the wrong one in.. Editing now

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes, when I know that I am working with numbers, I use this logic (`if result is not greater than zero`):

```
if (!$result['column']>0){

}
```

Comment: This is not correct because if filed may be null application may have different meaning for the field for example null may represent not checked and 0 false and 1 true