# if mysql query is null or doesn't exist?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a mysql query which gets 5 stars if a user rating is set to 5, like a star rating system. Another 4 of the same script which get 1, 2, 3 or 4 stars according to the rating 1-5.

What i want is for an image to be echoed if their are no results in the mysql table. I have tried the below but nothing is echoed. can someone show me what i would need to do please?

I've tried adding this bit of code but i just get an array error.

```
<?php
if (is_null($get_star_rating_set))  
{
    echo "HELLO";
}    
?>
```

Here's the code normally:

```
<?php
$get_star_rating_set = get_star_rating();
while ($rating = mysql_fetch_array($get_star_rating_set))
    if ($rating['rating'] == '0') { echo '
      <div class="star-rate">
        <table width="40%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="17%" align="left" valign="middle" scope="col"><img src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/favorites.png" id="R1" alt="0" style="cursor:pointer" title="Not at All" width="27" height="25" /></td>
            <td width="17%" align="left" valign="middle" scope="col"><img src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/favorites.png" id="R2" alt="1" style="cursor:pointer" title="Somewhat"   width="27" height="25" /></td>
            <td width="17%" align="left" valign="middle" scope="col"><img src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/favorites.png" id="R3" alt="2" style="cursor:pointer" title="Average"    width="27" height="25" /></td>
            <td width="17%" align="left" valign="middle" scope="col"><img src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/favorites.png" id="R4" alt="3" style="cursor:pointer" title="Good"       width="27" height="25" /></td>
            <td width="24%" align="left" valign="middle" scope="col"><img src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/favorites.png" id="R5" alt="4" style="cursor:pointer" title="Very Good"  width="27" height="25" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Check for NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576243/php-check-for-null) - And test with `var_dump()` what value you actually check for.

Answer (score 3):

When there are no results in the mysql table, you will never enter your `while` loop.

So you could add a condition that checks the number of rows around your `while` loop and put the image code in the `else` section (if there are no rows).

However, I recommend that you do all that in PDO or mysqli as the `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

in pseudo code:

```
do query
if number of rows > 0
  do normal stuff
else
  echo your no results image
```