# php mysql how to check NULL column with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

**how to check mysql `NULL` columns variable with php?**

my rows table (example):

`1 ---- james ------ italy`

`2 ---- joyee ------ NULL`

my fetch array from table:

```
$rows[0] = array('name' => 'james', 'country' => 'italy');
$rows[1] = array('name' => 'joyee', 'country' => NULL);
```

but my problem:

how to check NULL array element:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {

     if ($row['country'] == NULL) echo "country is null"; // not working
     if ($row['country'] == '') echo "country is null"; // not working
     if (is_null($row['country'])) echo "country is null"; // not working
     if (empty($row['country'])) echo "country is null"; // not working
     // what is  solution? how to check null?

}
```

update (var_dump):

```
'country' => null
```

Comment: Try null in lower case.

Comment: can you update your post with `var_dump($rows[1])` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Check for NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576243/php-check-for-null)

Comment: @NigelRen not working

Comment: @SahilGulati updated!

Comment: I just tested your example PHP code, and all four if statements correctly report that the data is null. I tested with PHP 5.5 and MySQL 8.0.0.

Comment: @BillKarwin thank you billkarwin ye is correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use is_null or === operator.

```
is_null($row['country'])
```