# Determine If Double Field Is Null From MySQLi Bound Results

Tags: php, null

I have a simple MySQLi statement with bound results.  One of the fields in that recordset is a double and results can be either NULL, 0 or other numeric value.

$wheels_cost is the recordset bound result.

The following logic should ignore null values and only process zero or other numeric values.

```
if($wheels_cost <> NULL){
    carry out a process
} else {
    the value is null so ignore
}
```

For some reason, the results I'm getting seem to reflect that the result is a zero rather than a null - which is not the desired result.

I've checked the DB and the field is null.

I need to tell the difference between a null and a zero value.

I've only tried the above logic and can't think why it doesn't work.  Should I be using isset() or is_null() or empty()?

Comment: is_null() would be the most correct way of checking this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Check for NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576243/php-check-for-null)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for feedback

Finished code below:

```
if(!is_null($wheels_cost)){
    carry out a process
} else {
    the value is null so ignore
}
```

Worked perfectly

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```php
if($wheels_cost is not NULL){
    # carry out a process
} else {
    # the value is null so ignore
}
```

I do not use mySQLi but I think the syntax should look like PostGreSQL

In PostGreSQL, the NULL value can not be equal or differentiated to any column or variable, since it is an unknown value and of an unknown type.

Examples here: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/is_null.php

Comment: There is no `is not` in php.