# Displaying based upon if NULL is found in Column

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a data base that I update on a daily basis. I am attempting to create a webpage that can be viewed internally. I want it to have a column that displays "Complete" if no NULL value is found within a specific column as I only need to update that one specific column and "Incomplete" if a null value is found

So here is a snippet of what I have tried:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:/var/www/html/dupi/GeoComply_Reported_Since_3_22_18.db");
$Array = array();

print "<table border=10 bordercolorlight=YELLOW bordercolordark=BLUE>";
print "<tr><td><u>Operator</u></td><td><u>Unique DUPIs</u></td><td><u>Total Reports</u></td></tr>";
$result = $db->query('SELECT operator, COUNT(DISTINCT dupi), COUNT(DISTINCT userID), dupi FROM reported GROUP BY operator ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT userID) DESC');
foreach($result as $row)
{
  print "<tr><td>".$row['operator']."</td>";
  print "<td>".$row['COUNT(DISTINCT dupi)']."</td>";
  print "<td>".$row['COUNT(DISTINCT userID)']."</td>";
  foreach($row['dupi'] as $rowdata){
 if ($rowdata == "NULL")
  {
    print "<td>InComplete</td>";
  } else {
    print "<td>Complete</td>";
   }
 }  
}
print "</table>";

$db = NULL;
```

An Example input might be

```
Home 2 1 abc
Pancake 4 3 NULL
```

For Pancake say the rows may look

```
Maple abc
Bacon NULL
```

UPDATE: 
So I found a work around as displayed below for those curious. I know it's not the best but my moto is if it works great if not fix it.

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:/var/www/html/dupi/GeoComply_Reported_Since_3_22_18.db");
print "<table border=10 bordercolorlight=YELLOW bordercolordark=BLUE>";
print "<tr><td><u>Operator</u></td><td><u>Unique DUPIs</u></td><td><u>Total Reports</u></td><td><u>DUPIs to be Filled</u></td></tr>";
$result = $db->query('SELECT operator, COUNT(DISTINCT dupi), COUNT(DISTINCT userID), dupi FROM reported GROUP BY operator ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT userID) DESC');

foreach($result as $row)
{

  print "<tr><td>".$row['operator']."</td>";
  print "<td>".$row['COUNT(DISTINCT dupi)']."</td>";
  print "<td>".$row['COUNT(DISTINCT userID)']."</td>";

$sql = "SELECT dupi, COUNT(*) FROM reported WHERE operator = '" .$row['operator'] ."' AND dupi is NULL";

$results = $db->query($sql);
foreach($results as $rows)
{

print "<td>" .$rows['COUNT(*)']. "</td></tr>";
}
}
print "</table>";

$db = NULL;
```

Comment: `$row['dupi']` is __not array__. So `if ($row['dupi'] == "NULL")`

Comment: I had tried that however it did not seem to be working as it only checks one row within the column. Basically I need it to select all of the dupi for each specific operators, loop through that and if it hits a null break and display incomplete else display complete

Comment: Run a different loop (while) and then a conditional in there instead. What you're doing now could fail if even one row isn't NULL. However, NULL and (not) empty are two different animals; remember that.

Comment: Use double quotes instead of "NULL".

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I would need a different SELECT statement then correct? I have the database setup in a way where it is either NULL or filled with the info I want so I know that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Queries like that can be tricky and I for one am no (SQL) guru and you may need one. From what I know and worked with, I used to use an alias for each column in the SELECT then checked with an `if(row==NULL)` or if there is NULL value for it and is left "empty", then check for "empty" instead. Sorry, that's about as far as I can go. A CASE could also come in handy but is a bit complex to write.

Comment: Check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576243/php-check-for-null helps with checking for nulls.

Comment: @NigelRen That would work for the single Row. My problem is I need the whole column checked to see if any rows within it have NULLs

Answer (score -1):

Rather than checking for NULL you should be checking for $rowdata;

if($rowdata):
  print "Complete";
else:
  print "InComplete";
endif;

Regards

Comment: Could you explain how this would solve the issue?
Please explain your answer :)

Comment: So this would more than likely work if it wasn't for the fact that this code only selects the first row in the column not all. So If the first row is filled it would be complete vs not where as I need the code to check all rows in the column