# PHP SQL: changing variable after checking for null on 'date'

Tags: php, sql, date, null, insert

```
    $wpdb->insert("events", array("title" => $_POST['title'],
                                  "date_start" => $_POST['date_start'],
                                  "date_end" => $_POST['date_end'],
                                  "country" => $_POST['country']));
    
    $yrdata_start = strtotime($_POST['date_start']);
    $yrdata_end = strtotime($_POST['date_end']);
    if ($_POST['date_end'] == '0000-00-00') {
        $event_date = date('F d, Y', $yrdata_start);
    } else {
        $event_date2 = date ('d', $yrdata_end);
        $event_date = date('F d - '.$event_date2.', Y', $yrdata_start);
    }
```

Problem: if my end date is null, the if condition does not show my date format with only one date number (eg January 11, 2022). Instead it shows up as: January 11 - 01, 2022). What can be fixed?

Here is the output: (no `date_end`)

[image: 1]

Here is the table, as you can see the date_end in the row is empty:

[image: 2]

So somehow this if condition does not check for null:

```
if ($_POST['date_end'] == '0000-00-00')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Check for NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576243/php-check-for-null)

Comment: Also, make column collation like an `update on the current timestamp`. so that at least the current date will save, rest you can update your code for any future date without any problem. Or at least make default value `NULL` so that `if ($_POST['date_end']){...}` will work straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Document

## List of Employees

ID First Name Last Name Email Phone Address Action   
 connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error); } 
// read all row from database table $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees"; $result = $connection->query($sql); 
if (!$result) { die("Invalid query: " . $connection->error); } 
// read data of each row while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo " " . $row["id"] . " " . $row["first_name"] . " " . $row["last_name"] . " " . $row["email"] . " " . $row["phone"] . " " . $row["address"] . "  Update Delete  "; }

$connection->close(); ?>

Nvm*emphasized text*

Comment: Hi @Jackk welcome to SO, looks like your answer needs formatting, it's not clear how your answer solves the problem here. Maybe reading this would help https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).